# Error in rename.sf(., bi_class_svi_ProjectB = bi_class) : internal error: can't find agr columns

Tags: r, dplyr, rename

I am trying to run a rename function. However, I am getting an error of Error in rename.sf(., bi_class_svi_ProjectB = bi_class) : internal error: can't find agr columns.

Also, below are classes for my data and for the bi_class variable:

```
    class (IDD_nhmap)
[1] "sf"         "grouped_df" "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
    class(IDD_nhmap$bi_class)
[1] "character"
```

**Here is my code:**

```
   df %>% dplyr::rename(bi_class_svi_ProjectB = bi_class).
```

Comment: Not clear about your case.  Are you trying to assign a function to a new object.  The error suggests that you are applying rename to a function instead of a tibble.  The usage of `rename` can be `head(iris) %>% rename(SL = Sepal.Length)`

Comment: This is missing something.  the first argument of `dplyr::rename()` should be a data frame, with additional arguments being newname = oldname pairs.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I added data frame to my rename function: df %>% dplyr::rename(bi_class_svi_ProjectB = bi_class). I got an error: Error in rename.sf(., bi_class_svi_ProjectB = bi_class) : 
  internal error: can't find `agr` columns